# Where to find a particular plastic component under the key of laptop keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboards

I have an [HP Omen X laptop 17.3"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075XHLDHC)

The "E" key came off as I was foolishly trying to remove to clean a spec of food underneath. In doing so, the plastic component which connects the key to the laptop broke and I need a replacement. Customer support only offers to replace the whole keyboard which seems quite excessive to me.

Specifically, the perimeter of the hole which allows the plastic to "hook" onto the laptop has broke.

Where might one find a spare plastic "foot" for a particular laptop's keyboard?

[image]

Comment: My gut feeling is I don't think you'll be able to find a spare part for something so small and specific as this. I think you might have better luck looking for broken HP Omen X's on ebay/amazon and trying to cannibalize parts from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the same company from which I've purchased key caps in the past, but a quick search with the terms "replacement key cap omen 17 laptop" resulted in a number of links. One of the more promising links: [Quickfix Laptop Keys](https://www.quikfixlaptopkeys.com/?page_id=16407) provides a number of Omen model identifiers. It appears that you would get three pieces including the plastic hinge and the cup.